# Ductless Mini Split System for Cooling, Heating, and Dehumidification

Tags: air-conditioning, heater, dehumidifier, mini-split

I have a 22x24 foot building that I'd like to heat, cool, and dehumidify in East Texas.

I'm specifically interested in purchasing a ductless mini split system to achieve this, but I have the following requirements:

1. The system must have a dehumidification mode, where it focus less on
   temperature and more on keeping the humidity to 40% or less.
2. The system should have a good energy efficiency rating for cooling
   and heating.
3. The system must be able to remember its settings after a power
   outage, so that it resumes those setting after power is regained.

I'm not looking load-calculation advise. Mainly, I'd appreciate any advise that could lead to meeting requirements 1 and 3 above.

I realize that brand and model recommendations are considered off-topic by the moderators here, but a 2017 example (meeting these requirements), would  be a great lead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a heating/cooling load calculation on your building with its specific design and insulation. It's a lot more than just the dimensions of the building. For example you need the volume of the building so you need the ceiling height.

Then select a make and model large enough to handle the load with the humidity option you require.

Asking for specific recommendations of make and model is considered off topic since it is asking for someone to shop for you.

Good luck!